# Consider the function $f(x) = e^{x^2}\ln(1+x)$ for $0 < x < 1$

Tags: taylor-expansion

[image]

So I was able to do the first half of this problem (part a), which was:

$$e^{x^2}\ln(1+x) \approx x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{4x^3}{3}$$

but I'm confused what my next step should be, for solving (part b). I don't quite understand what it is asking for. Any insight? Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of Taylor's Theorem? It relates the 'truncated' approximation of a Taylor series to an integral remainder, which is the approximation error.

Comment: Do you know about the Lagrange remainder? I think you should use that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder